# Arrange an array such that the average of 2 numbers does not lie between them

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math

As the question says, find an algorithm to arrange the array. This was a Facebook interview question.

The average needs to be exact. We do not round of, take floor or ceil of the average.

Edit : To quote an example, if the numbers are 1,2,5,9, then the arrangement {1,9,2,5} is valid but {1,5,9,2} is not since average of 1 and 9 is 5 and lies between them.

Comment: What? We have to arrange the array in such a way.

Comment: 2 3 4 not valid because (4+2)/2 = 3, 2 4 3 is a valid arrangement

Comment: lol average of 1 and 11 is 6

Comment: Actually, in your example, the average of 1 and 11 is 6.

Comment: You didn't read the [puzzle] tag description did you?

Comment: Example has been provided, expected result given. No code being asked, only algorithm

Comment: Presumably there's some restriction on duplicates?  An array that has 3 of the same number could not be ordered in such a way.

Comment: Also, I think this problem is simpler if we assume the numbers are integers, and your example implies that this might be the case.  Is it?

Comment: @AaronDufour My code still works with the appropriate type declarations for doubles. As far as I've tested it (e.g. {1, 1.5, 2.5, 2, 3, 3.25, 4}). I haven't checked it with complex numbers (an "exercise for the reader").

Comment: This depends on your definition of "between". If you think that, given {1, 2, 3, 4}, 2 is *not* between 1 and 4, then the problem is rather trivial. I don't believe a serious company like Facebook would ever consider such a thing for a tech interview. If you do think 2 is between 1 and 4, then the problem becomes much more interesting and challenging.

Comment: 2 is between 1 and 4 as in on the number line.

Comment: OK. Look closely at my comment to Captain Skyhawk's answer. Verify that no pair of numbers have their average between them. The array looks pretty chaotic but in fact there's some (not so) hidden order in it. Can you discover it?

Comment: See, there's the "trick" I was talking about ;) Answering questions like these makes someone a great math riddle problem solver. It does not, however, make them a good coder. Will never understand Silicone Valley's obsession with these types of questions.

Comment: Do you mean here the average of any two numbers does not lie between them or the numbers has to be consequent.

Answer (score 1):

Barring no funny business(duplicate entries), initial check showed this works:

```
    void check(ref int x, ref int y, int z)
    {
        if ((x + z) / 2 == y)
        {
            int temp = x;
            x = y;
            y = temp;
        }
    }

    int[] nums = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    for( int i = 0; i < nums.Count() - 3; i++)
    {
        check(ref nums[i], ref nums[i + 1], nums[i + 2]);
    }
```

Creating an algorithm for this on the spot that handles all cases(duplicate entries) though might be a little tricky. You would need some form of recursive function to go through and find the next entry that meets the criteria, yet doesn't break the list.

This might seem trivial, but consider the case of:

```
  { 2,2,2,4,5,6,2,2,2,2 }
```

You'd have to loop back to the beginning, which still doesn't have the right answer.

Comment: Now try this when "between a and b" does *not* mean "next to both a and b", but rather "somewhere in the interval from a to b".

Comment: MUCH more interesting of a problem. Much harder as well. Never felt these problems were right for interviews. There's often some "trick" that will lead you to the right answer. You could have an extremely competent coder that doesn't get your "trick" and you pass over him/her.

Comment: To ensure I'm not making stuff up, here's an array of numbers from 0 to 99, correctly arranged: 0 64 32 96 16 80 48 8 72 40 24 88 56 4 68 36 20 84 52 12 76 44 28 92 60 2 66 34 98 18 82 50 10 74 42 26 90 58 6 70 38 22 86 54 14 78 46 30 94 62 1 65 33 97 17 81 49 9 73 41 25 89 57 5 69 37 21 85 53 13 77 45 29 93 61 3 67 35 99 19 83 51 11 75 43 27 91 59 7 71 39 23 87 55 15 79 47 31 95 63.

Comment: @n.m. I can not discover the hidden order in the sequence you have generated, can you please elaborate on how did you generated this sequence ?

Comment: @Rohitchauhan OK try to look at these numbers in binary, might be a bit more obvious then

Answer (score 1):

Beaten to it by Captain Skyhawk, but...

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim a() As Integer = {9, 4, 7, 6, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1}
        Dim n = a.Length

        'TODO: check that sanity has a reasonable vale
        Dim sanity As Integer = n
        Dim ok As Boolean = False
        Dim temp As Integer

        While Not ok And sanity > 0
            ok = True
            For i = 0 To n - 3
                If ((a(i) + a(i + 2)) / 2) = a(i + 1) Then
                    temp = a(i)
                    a(i) = a(i + 1)
                    a(i + 1) = temp
                    ok = False
                End If

            Next

            sanity -= 1
        End While
        Console.WriteLine("OK: " & ok.ToString())

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", a))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk Heh :) I seem to like algorithms where a variable named `sanity` can be involved.

Comment: Now try this when "between a and b" does *not* mean "next to both a and b", but rather "somewhere in the interval from a to b".